# Matlab - add string index and numerical column to matrix

Tags: matlab, dataframe

I have a 4*3 matrix, and I would like to add column names, e.g.[1,2,3] and index name, e.g. ['A','B','C','D'] on it. How can I do this?

I'm thinking to transfer this matrix into data frame. but i saw matlab seems don't have this feature. Should i download any add-in or other functions?

thanks.

Comment: What do you want to be the output structure? It can't be matrix, so where do you want to store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matlab's `table` data structure as in

```
T = table( rand(4,3) );
```

and modify the metadata properties with

```
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'c1' 'c2' 'c3'};  % columns
T.Properties.RowNames = {'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'};      % rows
```

Column names can't be pure numbers though, because you need to access them as in

```
T.c1      % get the column c1
T{'A',:}  % get the row A
```

(`T.1` can't exist)

This is matlab's option to get something close to a dataframe.

Comment: This could be used for a dynamic name generation of column names - `arrayfun(@(n) strcat('C',num2str(n)),1:size(data,2),'Uni',0)`.

Comment: @Divakar nice one! in a similar vain, one can use `cellstr( ('A':'D')' ) ` for the row names

Comment: Ah I didn't know about that! Good find that one.